# Generic type Observer<T> requires 1 types argument(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I try to understand Observable in Angular 4. 
I am watching a video about it and I want to create my first Observable, but get an error in my IDE:

> Generic type Observer requires 1 types argument(s)

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const myObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next('first package');
        }, 2000);
    });
  }

}
```

I guess that I should add generic type like this: `Observable<any>`, but in the video which I watched the author **don't add any generics and it works**. 
Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: May have been using a non-generic implementation. You aren't.  Maybe he was using a much older version. You aren't. Maybe. Or maybe not. Doesn't really have anything to do with your present situation.

Comment: What do you mean? I've repeated each author's action step by step.

Comment: He means that you and the author might be using different versions of the library or compiler.  There's no way for us to know with certainty.  If the video is older than 6 months, I consider this very likely.

Comment: Ok, guys. I think that's it. Thanks for hints. Sorry for my mistakes in English.

Comment: Your English is perfectly fine, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is telling you exactly what to do. Generic type Observer requires 1 types argument(s). You just need to pass the data type that are using for your Observer. In this case it's a string 'first package'. So, in your `.create()` method set the observer data type to a string like this:

`observer: Observer<string>`